# JSON Deserialize

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am not able to deserialize my json

JSON

```
{
"Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse": {
    "Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult": {
        "Services.row": [
            {
                "Services.SR_NBR": "1-233391976021",
                "Services.SR_CREATED": "2018-04-26T13:44:25.000Z",
                "Services.SR_TYPE": "Corrective Repair",
                "Services.IB_SERIAL": "[]",
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

My Wrapper Class

```
public class CCP_ServiceReportWrapper {

public CCP_ServiceReportWrapper(){}

public CCP_ServiceReportWrapper(JSONParser parser) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                if (text == 'Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse') {
                    Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse = new Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse(parser);
                } else {
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'CCP_ServiceReportWrapper consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                    consumeObject(parser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static CCP_ServiceReportWrapper parse(String json) {
    return (CCP_ServiceReportWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CCP_ServiceReportWrapper.class);
}

public Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse {get;set;} // in json: Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse

public class Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse {
    public Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult {get;set;} // in json: Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult

    public Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult') {
                        Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult = new Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult {
    public List<Services_row> Services_row {get;set;} // in json: Services.row

    public Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'Services.row') {
                        Services_row = arrayOfServices_row(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Services_ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Services_row {
    public String SR_NBR {get;set;} // in json: Services.SR_NBR
    public String SR_CREATED {get;set;} // in json: Services.SR_CREATED
    public String SR_TYPE {get;set;} // in json: Services.SR_TYPE
    public String IB_SERIAL {get;set;} // in json: Services.IB_SERIAL

    public Services_row(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'Services.SR_NBR') {
                        SR_NBR = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Services.SR_CREATED') {
                        SR_CREATED = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Services.SR_TYPE') {
                        SR_TYPE = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'Services.IB_SERIAL') {
                        IB_SERIAL = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Services_row consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static List<Services_row> arrayOfServices_row(System.JSONParser p) {
    List<Services_row> res = new List<Services_row>();
    if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
    while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
        res.add(new Services_row(p));
    }
    return res;
}

public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
    Integer depth = 0;
    do {
        System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
            curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            depth++;
        } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
            curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            depth--;
        }
    } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
}}
```

This is how I am deserializing

```
CCP_ServiceReportWrapper ObjServiceReportWrapper = new CCP_ServiceReportWrapper();
                ObjServiceReportWrapper = (CCP_ServiceReportWrapper) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), CCP_ServiceReportWrapper.class);
                system.debug('ObjServiceReportWrapper++++ '+ObjServiceReportWrapper);
```

res.getBody() has the valid response but in debug I am getting as Null

Any Idea for this?
Thanks

Comment: would be a lot easier if you replace the namespaces 'Services.' from the key property.

Answer (score 5):

As Raul suggested, first replace the `Services.` from your JSON then create the wrapper class (You can use [Json2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)) and the class will be much simpler as below.

```
public class ServiceReportWrapper {

    public class ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult {
        public List<Row> row;
    }

    public ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse;

    public class ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse {
        public ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult;
    }

    public class Row {
        public String SR_NBR;
        public String SR_CREATED;
        public String SR_TYPE;
        public String IB_SERIAL;
    }


    public static ServiceReportWrapper parse(String json) {
        return (ServiceReportWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ServiceReportWrapper.class);
    }
}
```

Then replace the `Services.` dynamically from the response body by using replaceAll() method of String Class before parsing (Example : - `res.getBody().replaceAll('Services.','')`).

```
String json = '{"Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResponse": {"Services.ServiceContract_SAM_APIResult": {"Services.row": [{"Services.SR_NBR": "1-233391976021","Services.SR_CREATED": "2018-04-26T13:44:25.000Z","Services.SR_TYPE": "Corrective Repair","Services.IB_SERIAL": "[]"}]}}}';
json = json.replaceAll('Services.','');
ServiceReportWrapper obj = ServiceReportWrapper.parse(json);
System.debug(obj);
```